# Mockiito wrong return value?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mocking, mockito

Hello I have 2 tests for newInstance() method fragment.

But it looks like I'm doing something wrong, because Mockito is ignoring my bundle values.

```
    @Test
fun onNewInstanceTest_isNotArchive() {

    val bundle = Mockito.mock(Bundle::class.java)
    Mockito.doNothing().`when`(bundle).putBoolean(EventPlanner.EVENT_PLANNER_IS_ARCHIVE, false)

    val eventPlannerListFragment = EventPlannerListFragment.newInstance(bundle)

    val arguments = eventPlannerListFragment.arguments
    val isArchive = arguments!!.getBoolean(EventPlanner.EVENT_PLANNER_IS_ARCHIVE)

    assertFalse(isArchive)
}

@Test
fun onNewInstanceTest_isArchive() {

    val bundle = Mockito.mock(Bundle::class.java)
    Mockito.doNothing().`when`(bundle).putBoolean(EventPlanner.EVENT_PLANNER_IS_ARCHIVE, true)

    val eventPlannerListFragment = EventPlannerListFragment.newInstance(bundle)

    val arguments = eventPlannerListFragment.arguments
    val isArchive = arguments!!.getBoolean(EventPlanner.EVENT_PLANNER_IS_ARCHIVE)

    assertTrue(isArchive)
}
```

But it looks like the values are getting ignored.

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
at com.fs.wfm.ui.EventPlannerListFragmentTest.onNewInstanceTest_isArchive(EventPlannerListFragmentTest.kt:67)
```

**Thanks for any advice.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are not ignored you are simply not mocking them.

```
Mockito.doNothing()
    .`when`(bundle)
    .putBoolean(EventPlanner.EVENT_PLANNER_IS_ARCHIVE, true)
```

This line does not store the `true` under the given key. With this line you say "When I call `bundle.putBoolean()` method with specified arguments I want you to do nothing."
For mocking a query call you need a different Mockito method.

```
Mockito.doReturn(true)
    .`when`(bundle)
    .getBoolean(EventPlanner.EVENT_PLANNER_IS_ARCHIVE)
```

This line on the other hand tells Mockito to return true for `bundle.getBoolean()` calls with argument `EventPlanner.EVENT_PLANNER_IS_ARCHIVE`.

In other words, you need to mock query calls if you want it to return stub values.